# polynomial for maximums in A085000

Tags: number-theory

https://oeis.org/A085000
For an nbyn matrix one could substitute in the determinant that gives the maximum result n<--n+1, n+1<--n+2 and so on to give a number of different increasing results that could be used to find the polynomial expressing these terms.  Would this polynomial always be what would produce the maximum result for the determinant of the matrix being examined?  Thus for a 3by3 the simple polynomial is 332+$80*n$ gives 412 for n=1..9, 492 n=2..10, 572 for n=3..11 and so on.  Would this logic be valid for all larger matrices and their maximum determinants?

Answer (score 0):

For any **finite** sequence $a_1,\ldots,a_n$ you can find a polynomial $P$ such that $$\forall i\in\{1,\ldots, n\},\ \ P(i)=a_i.$$

There is however no reason to believe that this polynomial will still give out whatever expected values when $i>n$. To do this you would need to consider another polynomial, most likely of a higher degree. As the degree increases, to cover an infinite sequence you would need a "polynomial of infinite degree", which is something that does exist but is not called a polynomial.

Comment: Then that means A085000 is valid only when starting with n=1.  I guess if one enjoys finding polynomials, one could investigate when n=2,3,4....  That would mean time to invest in an exaflop machine.